# Change default value for column on h2 database to current timestamp

Tags: java, sql, h2

I have a h2 database with a schema that is auto generated via JPA/hibernate. Now I want to alter a not-null `timestamp` type column on the database to default to the current time.

I actually use [a trigger](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#triggers), and that works, but I'd like to know if there's a more elegant way to achieve this, something like (the following snippet *doesn't* work)

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

I looked at [the documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_table_alter) and tried some variants of the above "pseudo statement" but with now success.

Comment: I imagine you want to ADD CONSTRAINT + DEFAULT instead of ALTER COLUMN

Comment: With _doesn't work_ you mean...?

Comment: It's either invalid sql or it tries to parse the string "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" as a real timestamp. This definitely does not alter the column so that the current time get's persisted at inserts when I don't provide a value for "my_column".

Comment: You need to be more specific. The syntax for changing the default is correct. And the default **is** applied. See here for an example: http://pastebin.com/QjUQmaUi

Comment: Thanks a lot, to my surprise, now, that I just tried it again, it works. Maybe I had some typos in the first runs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks close, have you tried:

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> ALTER COLUMN <column name> SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, I have a typo in my question. I tried "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and that doesn't work. I'll update my question

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! I "thought" I did it like that but, obviously, I made some mistakes.